# Add a Exe Reference To a Project From build event

Tags: c#, .net

I have created an exe file as a part of pre build event. I want to add this exe as a reference to my project. Is there any command line option to do that ?

EDIT : I was able to solve the pblm i had by just making a xcopy to the required folder during pre build. References to exes need not be added to use it in code (using Proc).

Comment: Why do you want to add a _reference_ during build? That doesn't make much sense, as you can't use the types in the referenced assembly before it has been referenced (so it is not needed yet). Why can't you simply add the reference manually?

Comment: i created the exe file as a part of build event. I am not able to include it as a part of the project

Comment: What is your specific need? You have to be a lot more specific than that here on SO.

Comment: I have exe it in bin/Debug. I have a Test Project which will be accessing my exe file . What is the way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, please provide some more detail. So based off of this:

> I have exe it in bin/Debug. I have a Test Project which will be accessing my exe file . What is the way to do that ?

It looks like you just want an exe file to tag along when you compile your application. Well, that's easy.  Just drag your .exe file into your Visual Studio solution and in the `Properties` panel, change it to "Build Action - Content, Copy to Output Directory - Copy Always".

Then, your .exe file should always be copied to your output directory when compiled and you can reference it in your application as just WorkingDirectory/app.exe

Comment: i wish it is as easy as that . The pblm is i am creating that exe dynamically on pre build. How do i use it now ?

Comment: Are you creating it dynamically as in a separate project? If you are then you can try adding the project to the solution and referencing it from the other project.

Comment: am creating dynamically in another project..I want a way to add it thro command line. i can add reference it manually now. But i want a way to do it thro command line.

Comment: Why is doing it through the command line so important, and by command line do you mean a compile command or code?

Comment: i want to copy a exe created dynamically to TestData of another project.